# Wildfly datasource Enable is not working at runtime when configured through CLI

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

We are migrating from jboss Eap 6.4 to Wildfly. During migration, as part of our application installation, we will configure different xa-datasources in domain.xml. This configuration will be done through jboss-cli.sh.

After configuring the data sources, when deploying the ears, (particularly at *-ejb.jar) we are getting an error saying that the 'persistent unit' is not available and the deployment is rolled back.

Loggers are showing the below:

`WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"xxyy.ear/xxyy-ejb.jar#xxyyDBUnit\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.xxyyDS]"]`

Post restart of the jboss service, the same deployment works fine. So, we believe that the datasources configured in the domain.xml is not activated or enabled (although we have set the attribute 'enabled=true' for the xa-datasource. We could see the following warning while adding the xa-datasource in jboss.

`2021-09-21 16:57:48,308 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (Host Controller Service Threads - 8) WFLYJCA0093: The 'enable' operation is deprecated. Use of the 'add' or 'remove' operations is preferred, or if required the 'write-attribute' operation can used to set the deprecated 'enabled' attribute`

With this warning, we understood that the enable/disable operation has been removed in the jboss wildfly. Is there anyway we can make it enabled on the runtime without restart of the jboss service.
Below are the commands which we use to create the xa-datasource in wildfly.

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS:add(use-java-context=true,use-ccm=false,driver-name=com.mysql,transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED,min-pool-size=15,max-pool-size=150,pool-prefill=true,flush-strategy=IdleConnections,valid-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker",stale-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker",exception-sorter-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter",set-tx-query-timeout=true,blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000,idle-timeout-minutes=1,query-timeout=300,prepared-statements-cache-size=100,share-prepared-statements=true,jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xxyyDS",user-name=jboss,password="${VAULT::ds_MySqlDS::password::1}")
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=DatabaseName:add(value=xxyy_db)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=ServerName:add(value=xx-cluster)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=AutoReconnectForPools:add(value=true)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=AutoReconnect:add(value=true)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=useSSL:add(value=false)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS:enable
```

Any inputs on how to enable the xa-datasource on runtime would help us.

Comment: Some cli commands result can be you must reload... Then you run :reload command on cli, and jbos restarted. Perhaps after add datasource this is wildfly's answer.

Comment: When you run the CLI commands what is the output from the result?

Comment: Thanks Laszlo, we need to remove the configuration to enable the datasource to have the deployment work fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running through many trial and error method, we found that when adding the datasources by default it will be in enabled state. So no need to do explicitly enable when adding a datasource.

So we removed the below line from the list of CLIs.

***/profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS:enable***

Post removing the line, the configuration of datasources through CLI and the deployment of ears went fine without issues. Posting this solution as it will be helpful for others who are facing similar kind of issue.

Finally our datasource CLIs will be like the ones below.

> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS:add(use-java-context=true,use-ccm=false,driver-name=com.mysql,transaction-isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED,min-pool-size=15,max-pool-size=150,pool-prefill=true,flush-strategy=IdleConnections,valid-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker",stale-connection-checker-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker",exception-sorter-class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter",set-tx-query-timeout=true,blocking-timeout-wait-millis=5000,idle-timeout-minutes=1,query-timeout=300,prepared-statements-cache-size=100,share-prepared-statements=true,jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/xxyyDS",user-name=jboss,password="${VAULT::ds_MySqlDS::password::1}")
> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=DatabaseName:add(value=xxyy_db)
> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=ServerName:add(value=xx-cluster)
> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=AutoReconnectForPools:add(value=true)
> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=AutoReconnect:add(value=true)
> /profile=full-ha/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS/xa-datasource-properties=useSSL:add(value=false)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the datasource via the CLI:

`/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxyyDS:write-attribute(name=enabled,value=true)`

It might be required to reload:

`:reload`

Comment: Thanks Christian. Yes, After adding the write-attribute, we need to reload the jboss service. In our application, if we execute :reload, jboss is not reloading, rather its hanging. We have found out that we don't need to enable or write any attribute like 'enabled'. By default, the datasources are in enabled state. After removing 'enable' the deployment went fine without any issues. Thanks for taking time and answering the query.